# Clickable Hyperlinks Android

Tags: android

In my Android app, I would like to create text links that act like buttons.

[image]

I want the links to behave exactly like hyperlinks in HTML pages but I want them to work like Android buttons when they are clicked.

How can I achieve that?

(Note: `Linkify` is not what I am looking for here. I don't want links to web pages. I want the links to work like ordinary buttons. `SpannableString` might work but I am not sure how to do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Clickable Span` as suggested.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

```
String s ="Your text";
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1);
SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString(s); 
ss.setSpan(new  MyClickableSpan(s), 0, ss.length(),  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(newForegroundColorSpan(Color.Blue),0,ss.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(ss1);
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{    
String clicked;
public MyClickableSpan(String string) {

    super();
    clicked =string;
    }

    public void onClick(View tv) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       

   }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
       ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
    }
    }
```